# PostgreSQL: 8.3/8.4 interface chages?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-8.3, interface

I would like to upgrade a PostgreSQL 8.3 server to PostrgreSQL 8.4. There are many software components that interact with the server over the network, and I am concerned with compatibility issues.

Is there any interface change between the different versions of PostgreSQL, as far as an external component is concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, without knowing your system (inside and out), it's going to be difficult for anyone to tell you how an upgrade is going to impact you.

I'd recommend checking the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html) to verify that the upgrade path won't mess up the application.

Here are a couple changes that I noticed that you might need to know about:

- Remove `ipcclean` utility command
- Changes in the `TRUNCATE` and `LOCK` statements
- `SELECT DISTINCT` and `UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT` no longer always produce sorted output
- Disallow `LOCK TABLE` outside a transaction block
- Remove support for the (insecure) `crypt` authentication method
- Modify the ALTER TABLE syntax to allow all reasonable combinations for tables, indexes, sequences, and views

I'd recommend trying this on a test machine first (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any changes that break backwards-compatibility - see [here](http://sql-info.de/postgresql/gotchas-administration.html#2_1) for some general upgrade hints as you can't use [pg_upgrade](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/05/19/waiting-for-9-0-pg_upgrade/)

You will of course want to test the upgrade away from your production environment first

Answer (score 1):

You should ***carefully(!)*** read the changes from [8.4 to 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html). See if anything relates to your setup and fix it accordingly.